# How to set double input in keras?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, google-colaboratory

I am designing a Neural Network with 2 inputs (2 images). I made a generator, which output is: `((img1, img2), segmentatedImg)` (with yield). How to train this model?

`fit_generator` doesn't work on such model.

Comment: Can you tell us why fit_generator does not work? And also it would be appreciated if you provide us a minimal code.